# Explanation of transformation of covariate like position (longitude + latitude)

Tags: predictor

For the behavior of some animals, I have covariates like position (longitude and latitude). I want to use a linear model, i.e. regression.

I read in a paper somewhere that when it comes to a covariate like position, then if $Y$ is a response, then one should use $EY = F(Position)$, where $F$ is a function $$F(Position) = \alpha f_1(Position) + \beta f_2 (Position) + ...$$

where $f_1, f_2, ...$ can be polynomial or trigonometric functions.

Can somebody explain this further?

In particular, **why** should we do this, why is it not just enough to use the standard $EY = \alpha \cdot Position$, and **how** do we know which $f_i$ functions to pick?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are talking about when you don't tell us what your response variable is. Why isn't position list as two variables (latitude and longitude)?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable without more information, as @MichaelChernick notes. You may want to look at questions tagged [feature construction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-construction?sort=votes&pageSize=15). (For broadness, note that in a sense, much of "deep learning" is a [sophisticated automated way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_learning) of doing this!)

Comment: The paper is partly correct insofar as lat and lon have nonlinear relationships with inherent geometric properties of the earth such as distance, angle and area: but that's a distraction. The real issue in modeling concerns *how those variables might be related to the response.*  It is exceedingly rare that a response is truly related to coordinates as a polynomial, but trigonometric functions of the *longitude* at least are meaningful--they give consistent values no matter how you represent the longitude. How to find appropriate $f_i$ is a very broad question applicable to all models.